# "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined" in index.html of electron-forge app with react template

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron, node-modules

I am creating an electron-forge app with react template

```
electron-forge init myApp --template=react
cd myApp
npm install
```

But somehow I only get a white screen, and the developer console shows only this error

```
"Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined" at index.html:inline_0.js:2
```

[image: Error Code]

The code of the index.html looks like this:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
</head>

<body style="overflow: hidden; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); margin: 0">
  <div id="App"></div>
</body>

<script>
  import React from 'react';
  import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
  import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader';
  const render = () => {
    const App = require('./app').default;
    ReactDOM.render(<AppContainer><App /></AppContainer>,
      document.getElementById('App'));
  }
  render();
  if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept(render);
  }
</script>


</html>
```

Because the error tells something like require is not defined, I think there is something wrong with node

The versions:
Electron-forge: `5.2.4`

Electron: `v9.1.0`

node: `v14.5.0`

npm: `6.14.7`

Operating system: `Manjaro Linux`

Comment: It seems like `--template=react` on electron-forge is broken, and has been so for last 3 years. Have you considered using `--template=webpack` and adding react dependencies manually? I can add a answer with the details, if that option is viable.

Comment: Yeah this would be an option, if I can still use node modules in react. As far as I know there is no other option anyway, because the 5.x isn't fixed anymore due to resource limits. It would be very friendly, if you could make a detailed description :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nodeIntegration is now false by default in 5.0.0.

The electronjs FAQ has some sample code on how to set this value.

```js
let win = new BrowserWindow({
  webPreferences: {
    nodeIntegration: true
  }
})
win.show()
```

Comment: oh my fault, this really solved the problem. I accidentally only wrote

```nodeIntegration: true
```
instead of your solution

Comment: Note that generally it's bad to give the browser window access to the node instance.